# Possible to find distinct _id.field values using regex in MongoDB?

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB collection with _id built up by key, value and metric. I want to find all distinct metrics for a particular key value pair. How do I best achieve this? I.e. for the following data

```
> db.schedule.find()
{ "_id" : { "key" : "source", "value" : "a", "metric" : "index.references.added.all" }, "nextCheck" : ISODate("2016-07-07T14:36:27.760Z") },
{ "_id" : { "key" : "source", "value" : "a", "metric" : "index.references.added.some" }, "nextCheck" : ISODate("2016-07-07T14:36:27.761Z") },
{ "_id" : { "key" : "source", "value" : "b", "metric" : "index.references.added.all" }, "nextCheck" : ISODate("2016-07-07T14:36:27.760Z") },
{ "_id" : { "key" : "source", "value" : "b", "metric" : "index.references.added.some" }, "nextCheck" : ISODate("2016-07-07T14:36:27.759Z") }
```

I want to achieve something along the lines of this

```
db.schedule.distinct("_id.metric", {_id : {"key" : "source", "value" : "a", "metric" : {$regex : "all"}}})

["index.references.added.all", "index.references.added.some"]
```

Currently this doesn't return anything. I have confirmed that

```
db.schedule.distinct("_id.metric")
["index.references.added.all", "index.references.added.some"]
```

works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#embedded-documents) to access the embedded field.

```
db.schedule.distinct(
    "_id.metric", 
    { "_id.key": "source", "_id.value" : "a", "_id.metric": /all/ }
)
```